# Rails Slim syntaxe error with method: :delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

My Slim code in my index view

```
td= link_to 'Destroy', task, method: :delete, data: confirm: 'Are you sure?'
```

generates a Slim error

```
syntax error, unexpected tLABEL ...method: :delete, data: confirm: 'Are you sure?'))).to_s)); ... ^
```

Do you have a clue and understand the error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that Slim doesn't like the hash "symbole: value" syntaxe.

Indeed, this code is working :

```
td= link_to 'Destroy', board, :method => :delete, :data => {:confirm => 'Are you sure?'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is just here:

```
data: confirm: 'Are you sure?'
```

change it to

```
data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}
```